# Image upload via ajax php and return image name in hidden input field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am having a form with one image upload field.

I want to upload image file with ajax and fill up one hidden field in form with returned image name via ajax success BEFORE SUBMITTING MAIN FORM with other input fields like name, email, mobile etc......

Following code I have tried but no luck...

**HTML form code :**

```
<label>Upload File:</label>
  <input name="userFile" id="userFile" type="file" class="form-control"><br>
  <button name="marksheet_upload" id="marksheet_upload" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>

<label>Image Final Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="intern_marksheet_image" name="intern_marksheet_image"> 
 // This above field will be hidden and after image file upload, this value should get via ajax response

<div id="loader-icon" style="display:none;"><img src="images/123.gif"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
// File upload via Ajax
   $("#marksheet_upload").click(function(e) {
     var dataimg = new FormData();
     var marksheet = $('#userFile')[0].files[0];
    //append files
    dataimg.append('userFile', marksheet);
    
    
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'register-file-upload.php',
        data: dataimg,
        contentType: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loader-icon').show();
        },
        
        success: function(response){
            if(response.upload == 'ok'){
                $('#intern_marksheet_image').val(response.image_name);
                $('#loader-icon').html(response.image_error);
                
            }else {
                $('#intern_marksheet_image').val('xxx');
                $('#loader-icon').html(response.image_error);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP ajax url -

**`register-file-upload.php` code :**

```
 <?php
  function randStrGen601($len){
    $result = "";
    $chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $charArray = str_split($chars);
      for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
        $randItem = array_rand($charArray);
        $result .= "".$charArray[$randItem];
      }
    return $result;
  }

$error = false;
$imagetypeerror = false;

if (isset($_FILES['userFile'])) {
            $avatar1 = $_FILES['userFile'];
            $avatarname1 = $_FILES['userFile']['name'];
            $avatarsize1 = $_FILES['userFile']['size'];
            $minsize1    = 100000; // 100 KB 
            $maxsize1    = 500000; //500 KB 
            $acceptable1 = array(
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/jpg',
                'image/png'
            );
            
            if(function_exists('finfo_open')){    //(PHP >= 5.3.0, PECL fileinfo >= 0.1.0)
                $fileinfo1 = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                    if(!empty($avatar1['tmp_name'])){
                        if (!in_array(finfo_file($fileinfo1, $avatar1['tmp_name']), $acceptable1)) {
                            $msg  = "Marksheet Image is not a valid image, Only 'JPG' & 'PNG' Types Are Allowed";                           
                            $error = true;
                            $imagetypeerror = true;
                            
                            $data['upload'] = "Err";
                            $data['image_error'] = $msg;
                            $data['image_name'] = "";
                        }
                    }
            }else if(function_exists('mime_content_type')){  //supported (PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5)
                    if (!in_array(mime_content_type($avatar1['tmp_name']), $acceptable1)) {
                            $msg  = "Marksheet Image is not a valid image, Only 'JPG' & 'PNG' Types Are Allowed";
                            $error = true;
                            $imagetypeerror = true;
                            
                            $data['upload'] = "Err";
                            $data['image_error'] = $msg;
                            $data['image_name'] = "";
                        }
            }else{
                if (!@getimagesize($avatar1['tmp_name'])) {  //@ - for hide warning when image not valid
                            $msg  = "Marksheet Image is not a valid image, Only 'JPG' & 'PNG' Types Are Allowed";
                            $error = true;  
                            $imagetypeerror = true;
                    
                            $data['upload'] = "Err";
                            $data['image_error'] = $msg;
                            $data['image_name'] = "";
            }
            }
            
        if(!$imagetypeerror){
            if( (!isset($avatarname1)) || (empty($avatarname1)) || ($avatarsize1 == 0)) {                               
                            $error = true;
                            $msg= "Please browse and upload the Marksheet Image";                               
                            $data['upload'] = "Err";
                            $data['image_error'] = $msg;
                            $data['image_name'] = "";
            }
            if ( (!empty($avatarname1)) && ($avatarsize1 >= $maxsize1)) {                               
                            $error = true;
                            $msg = 'Marksheet Image Size Is Too Large. Image Must Be Less Than 500 KB.';
                            $data['upload'] = "Err";
                            $data['image_error'] = $msg;
                            $data['image_name'] = "";
            }
            if ( (!empty($avatarname1)) && ($avatarsize1 <= $minsize1)) {                               
                            $error = true;
                            $msg = 'Marksheet Image Size Is Too Small. Image Must Be Greater Than 100 KB.';
                            $data['upload'] = "Err";
                            $data['image_error'] = $msg;
                            $data['image_name'] = "";
            }
        }





 if(!$error){    
         $targetDir = "uploads/intern/";    
         $fileName = $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name']; 
         $udx = date("YmdHis");
         $random2 = randStrGen601(4);
         $fileName1 = strtolower($fileName);
         $fileName2 = str_replace(" ", "_", $fileName1);
         $targetFilePath = $targetDir.$fileName2; 
 
       // Upload file to the server 
         move_uploaded_file($fileName2, $targetFilePath));
      
        $error = false;
        $data['upload'] = "ok";
        $data['image_error'] = "File Uploaded Successfully";
        $data['image_name'] = $fileName2;       
 
     }
 } 
//returm $data; 
  echo $data;

?>
```

With this code, I am just getting "XXX" as Image File Name in hidden input field and Loading Image. Image not getting uploaded.

Comment: The usual UI design is : when the user has selected the file, upload starts (no need to click a button)

Comment: @KenLee Thnx for update. I just tried changing on Change file input id in js...but till no luck for hidden image file name

Comment: @KenLee I think I am missing something in register-file-upload.php code... as $data['upload.]= "OK"; is not getting back...

Comment: `echo $data;` - you can not output an array using echo, that will only ever result in the _text_ `Array`. You should encode your array as JSON, and then add `dataType: "json"` to your jquery AJAX call options.

Comment: @CBroe  I tried dataType: "json", but then ajax not working... full page relaoded...

Comment: Is your PHP script actually _returning_ JSON now?

Comment: @CBroe No..because Ajax script failing if added dataType: "json"

Comment: Of course it will fail when you instruct jQuery to parse the response as JSON, but then make your PHP script return something that is _not_ JSON ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code has a few errors:

1. The closing braces / brackets are not matching the opening braces / brackets, so add `})` to the end of `$(document).ready` block
2. Remove the last `)` from  `move_uploaded_file($fileName2, $targetFilePath));` (otherwise the PHP will definitely fail)
3. Use `echo json_encode($data)` instead of  `echo $data` in your PHP script, otherwise we cannot properly return the array data
4. Add `dataType: "json",` in your ajax block, so that the system evaluates the response of ajax as JSON and returns a JavaScript object
5. I have slightly changed the filename, filename1 and filename2 assignment lines , since I think they are not quite logical
6. Please make sure `/uploads/intern/` directory is writable so that the file can be uploaded

So, the HTML / JS will be:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<label>Upload File:</label>
  <input name="userFile" id="userFile" type="file" class="form-control"><br>
  <button name="marksheet_upload" id="marksheet_upload" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>

<label>Image Final Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="intern_marksheet_image" name="intern_marksheet_image"> 
<div id="loader-icon" style="display:none;">Uploading....</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#marksheet_upload").click(function(e) {
     var dataimg = new FormData();
     var marksheet = $('#userFile').prop("files")[0];
     dataimg.append('userFile', marksheet);

// if you want to pass additional data say string1, then add something like
//dataimg.append("string1","KEN1");
    
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'register-file-upload.php',
        data: dataimg,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loader-icon').show();
        },
        
        success: function(response){
            if(response["upload"] == 'ok'){
                $('#intern_marksheet_image').val(response["image_name"]);
                $('#loader-icon').html(response["image_error"]);
                
            }else {
                $('#intern_marksheet_image').val('- failed -');
                $('#loader-icon').html("Not Successful");
            }
        }
    });
});

   })

</script>
```

and the PHP will be as follows (Note: For the image validation part - I remove them so that you can focus on the file upload part, but you may add it back)

```
<?php
function randStrGen601($len){
    $result = "";
    $chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $charArray = str_split($chars);
      for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
        $randItem = array_rand($charArray);
        $result .= "".$charArray[$randItem];
      }
    return $result;
  }

$error = false;
$imagetypeerror = false;

/*

The image validation part - I remove them so as to focus on the file upload

*/

 if(!$error){    
         $targetDir = "./uploads/intern/";    
         $fileName = $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name']; 
//         $udx = date("YmdHis");
         $random2 = randStrGen601(4);
         $fileName1 = $random2 . "_". $_FILES['userFile']['name'] ;
         $fileName2 = str_replace(" ", "_", $fileName1);
         $targetFilePath = $targetDir.$fileName2; 
 
       // Upload file to the server 
         move_uploaded_file($fileName, $targetFilePath);
      
        $error = false;
        $data['upload'] = "ok";
        $data['image_error'] = "File Uploaded Successfully";
        $data['image_name'] = $fileName2;       
 
     }
  
//returm $data; 
  echo  json_encode($data);

?>
```

**Additional Point** (one may try later)

As I have mentioned, The usual UI design is : when the user has selected the file, upload starts (no need to click a button)

In order to do it , change

```
  $("#marksheet_upload").click(function(e) {
```

to

```
  $("#userFile").change(function(e) {
```